# Proof by contradiction : if n or m are not divisible by 3 then the sum or the difference is also not divisible by 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, divisibility

I'm just trying to prove this by contradiction:
$$3\nmid n \vee 3\nmid m \implies 3\nmid (n+m) \vee 3\nmid(n-m)$$
Things I know:
$$n,m \in \mathbb{Z}  $$
$$n|m \Leftrightarrow \exists x\in \mathbb{N}^+ : n*x=m$$
I negate the assumption:
$$3|n \wedge 3|m \implies 3|(n+m) \wedge 3|(n-m)$$
That implies:
$$\exists x \in \mathbb{N}^+ : 3x=(n+m)$$
I tried to divide this equation by $3$:
$$x=\frac{n+m}{3}$$
I wanted to show that $x\not\in \mathbb{N}^+$ and therefore is this a contradiction to the definition. But I know this is not correct. 
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, by contradiction, that $3$ divides both $n+m$ and $n-m$ (that is, negate the thesis).

Then $3$ also divides $(n+m)+(n-m)=2n$. Since $3\nmid2$, we get $3\mid n$.

Can you show that $3$ divides also $m$?

---

Actually this is not a proof by contradiction, which is not necessary. The statements “$A$ implies $B$” and “not $B$ implies not $A$” are completely equivalent. In formal terms, the propositional formula
$$
(A\to B)\leftrightarrow(\lnot B\to\lnot A)
$$
is a tautology.

Comment: Don't actually understand the step "Since $ 3\nmid 2 $ we get $3|n$"

Comment: @MonsieurMolly It's a basic property of prime numbers: if $p$ is a prime number and $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. It's, essentially, the unique factorization property.

Comment: $(n+m)-(n-m)= 2m $ and then we get $3 | m $ but I actually wanted to show $3 \nmid m $ didn't I?

Comment: No, you want to show that you get a contradiction with respect to "$3\nmid n$ or $3\nmid m$”. The negation of this is “$3\mid n$ *and* $3\mid m$”.